# Команда "atop" debian

Tags: ssh, debian

Разъясните, пожалуйста, что это красным выделяется? И вообще, тут всё плохо? И как исправлять это дело?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60474/atop-shows-red-line-vmcom-and-vmlim-what-does-it-mean
Вот подробный ответ.

Comment: @Влад Дяченко, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.